# Session gets lost in p:media

Tags: jsf, session, primefaces, media, view-scope

I try to display `*.avi` file in PrimeFaces component `p:media`. I do everything like in showcase

```
<p:media value ="#{viewScopedBean.content}" player="windows" width="500" height="500"></p:media>
```

When I try to display movie I am logged. Method `viewScopedBean.content` calls 4-5 times in one request but for the thrid/fourth time in each request my logged user session gets lost and it causes an exception in my web application. I want to say that no other players in p:media do not cause that that situation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: But plain html does not support `*.avi` format...

Comment: I think it is Windows Media Player plugin problem. When I use this : http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html the problem still exists...

Comment: `viewScopedBean.content` method only returns URL to the rest webservice which download data from my Alfresco and returns data in response...

Comment: But `<p:media>` to display `*.avi` files use WindowsMediaPlayer, probably it isn't plain html?

Comment: So do you think that my session gets lost because my application does not support `Range` requests?